# Why is the pid for my iex sessions always the same?

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

In between restarts of `iex` process, on my machine, why is its pid always the same?

```
iex> self
#PID<0.81.0>
iex>
^C
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
```

Again

```
iex> self
#PID<0.81.0>
```

Why is the `pid` value always `#PID<0.81.0>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Process ids are assigned in order, and every time you start `iex`, the same number of processes are started.

Comment: The same thing happens when I start 2 iex sessions in different tabs at the same time. Any particular reason why?

Comment: Process ids in the two sessions are independent of each other, so you'd normally expect to get the same result.